# sencha Touch Card layout not working properly

Tags: sencha-touch

Iam using sencha touch for building mobile application, Ia m using card layout switch in my tab panel. sometimes the card layout is not working properly. Please help me regarding this.

```
App.views.TabPanelView = Ext.extend(Ext.TabPanel, {
cardSwitchAnimation: {
            type: 'slide',
            cover: true
        },

        defaults: {
            scroll: 'horizontal'
        },
       items: [item1, item2,item3,item4,item5]
  }
  }
```

Comment: when am switching from item5 to item1 sometimes it's not showing the item1 tab. sometimes it's works fine like a charm.

Comment: Could you give the declaration of the items or at least their type (panel, list, nested list...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple Just Put `cover: false` in your cardSwitchAnimation. Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

First you should change `horizantal` to `horizontal`